# How to filter data on page load using jQuery DataTables plugin?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery DataTables plugin in my application and am displaying a set of data with multiple years.  When the page loads, I'd like the data to start filtered to the current year.  Is it possible to have the plugin filter data when the page loads?

Comment: About this being off-topic - nope.  It's clearly an issue, and it's not easy to locate the solution from the DataTables site.  This question comes up in searches within the first 10 links.  Besides - the answer given by Georg Engel is a good one.

Comment: This isn't off-topic, but it did need more information from the asker.  I will say that Georg Engel's answer is a good answer to a different question, but does not answer this question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [Datatables API](http://datatables.net/api) says:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

    /* Filter immediately */
    oTable.fnFilter( 'test string' );
} );
```

If you need to Filter only a specific column, use (zero-based) columnIndex as second parameter:

```
    oTable.fnFilter( 'test string', columnIndex );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try

JQuery DataTables Column Filtering plugin

Column filtering functionality is one of the functionalities that you will need to implement using the custom examples on the DataTables site. As an alternative you can use the DataTables Column filter plugin where most of the code exmaples from the DataTables site are encapsulated.

To implement and customize column filtering you will ned to take DataTables plugin and column filtering plugin and enhance your HTML table with basic !dataTable plugin and then with columnFilter plugin as shown in the example:

```
 $("#dataTableId").dataTable().columnFilter();
```

see **text - default behavior. You can define whether the regular expression or smart filtering will be used in the filtering,**

here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/wiki/ColumnFilter

refer for more details http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/

for live example http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/default.html

**EDIT**

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/scripts-pack.js"></script>  

This plugin will then create the filters in a row in the THEAD element of the table so add this if it is not already there.


<table id='demotable'>        
    <thead>
        <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th></tr>        
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Value 1</th><th>Value 2</th><th>Value 3</th></tr>        
        ....
    </tbody>
</table>

Hook in your table when the document is loaded.


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#demotable).tableFilter();
});
```

refer http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/Guido/post/2009/06/29/JQuery-Table-Filter-Plugin.aspx