# Create Datatable columns according to if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, render

Below I attached my table.
[image] I want to create a datatable with two columns price and schedule_from if TYPE=='retail'.
this is my code.

```
 $('#retail-price-history').DataTable({
   data: record.retail_history,  
   destroy: true,
   searching: false,
   ordering: false,
   dom: '<<"row"<"col">>t<"row"<"col">>>',
   columns: [     
     {
         data: "price",
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         return data/100;
      }
      },
      { data: "scheduled_from"
      
      
      }]


});
```

This is my json record.retail_history

```
{[
    
    TYPE: "retail"
    id: 6069714
    price: 899
    scheduled_from: "2022-01-20"
    sku: 1435530
]
    [
    TYPE: "cost"
    id: 123
    price: 599
    scheduled_from: "2022-11-01"
    sku: 1435530
]}
```

how to populate data on my data table if the condition satisfy  TYPE =='retail'.
Now According to my code its populating all data either TYPE is 'retail' or 'cost'

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is regarding this code?

Comment: Sorry, I've just edited

Comment: You can filter on load demonstrated in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938142/how-to-filter-data-on-page-load-using-jquery-datatables-plugin)

Comment: Your function makes no reference to `re`, so of course it's not filtering only those records. What is `record.retailHistory`? Is your "JSON array" JSON (a string) or an array? What variable is it in?